# Google API not loading on my page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to set up the google map api on my website so for part of a delivery service I'm offering. I copied the code directly from the sample on developers.google.com but for some reason my map wont load on my page!Ive gone through the code multiple times and cant get it to load...HELP!

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBPiGhEEN1WjNHOtVoOMufbwsj_thBse2w&sensor=true">
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
```

The html:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

<div class="map-canvas" style= "height: 100%">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you using your own API key?

Comment: Also, try adding `<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` just prior to your other `script` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROADMAP' of undefined`

This:

```
      mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

Should be:

```
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
```

The major problem is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null` because your page doesn't have a div with id="map-canvas":

```
<div class="map-canvas" style= "height: 100%">
```

Should be:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style= "height: 100%;">
```

You are also calling initialize twice, change:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

To:

```
<body>
```

Complete page (works locally):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body >

<div id="map-canvas" style= "height: 100%;">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! that seemed to work. Just another question: i want to size the map using px length instead of %, but its not resizing when i do that. do i have to change the body and html styling to px too?

Comment: This should be another question (if you can't find a previously existing one that addresses your problem). Changing the inline style applied to the map-canvas div always works for me.  Are you doing something like style="height:500px; width:600px;"?

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues

1. you use getElementById, but you give your div a *class* of map-canvas
2. it's **M**apTypeId (capital M)
3. you need to give your map-canvas div a fixed height

Also, since you are using addDomListener, it's unnecessary to also have an onload event on the body tag too.  I would just use addDomListener.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBPiGhEEN1WjNHOtVoOMufbwsj_thBse2w&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <style>
      #map-canvas{
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas">

    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

</html>
```